# How do you modify horizontal blue lines in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grids, document-setup, cc-2017

I did run across [Horizontal blue lines resembling notebook paper?](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3645770#3645770) and when searching through the documentation under [Layout grids](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/layout-grids.html) it indicates:

[image]

However, in CC 2017 there is only `Liquid Layout`, so how can you remove or modify horizontal blue lines in a document?

When I search and toggle the 'Extras' panel they're still present in the document:

[image]

When I reference [Shortcut to hide all guides and stuff (inDesign)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/shortcut-to-hide-all-guides-and-stuff-indesign) that only allow for preview when using <kbd>w</kbd> and doesn't help me understand where these line are located and in what panel.

How can you modify (move, create or delete) an Indesign's horizontal blue lines on a pre-existing document not a new document setup?

Comment: The first comment under that question calls it a "baseline grid"; and under that name, it can be found in the online help. I see no direct link to Liquid Layouts on https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/grids.html ...

Comment: There's really no way to tell what these lines are without access to the document.  These could be a grid, or guides even, but they could also just be lines. They could be locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be a baseline grid.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open up the Preferences, then go to 'Grids → Document Grid' and then you can change the color from blue to anything and adjust the spacing between these. I like to choose a very light gray colour for baseline grids, so these are not very prominent when set to visible.

Doing this with an open document affects the document, while doing this with no open documents will change the overall defaults.

To toggle these on and off go to 'View → Grids & Guides → Show/Hide Baseline Grid'.

[image]